# TEXTJOIN with VSTACK and looping and ignoring blanks

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

This is far beyond my excel formula comfort, but here's what I'm trying to do; I have a series of names along colA, and a series of headers in row1. I would like to create a single column of data that joins every name in A with every header in row 1 using a formula, so that as new entries are added into colA, this formula-driven column is automatically updated. To make it extra complicated, if the cross-cell doesn't have an X in it (so dog • pink does but cow • pink does not), I would like that value to be skipped/omitted.

Sample data:

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | pink | red | orange |
| dog | X | X |  |
| cat | X |  | X |
| horse | X |  | X |
| cow |  | X |  |

what i have so far is this, and it works a bit

```
=VSTACK(TEXTJOIN(" • ", TRUE, A2,$B$1),TEXTJOIN(" • ", TRUE, A2,$C$1),TEXTJOIN(" • ", TRUE, A2,$D$1),TEXTJOIN(" • ", TRUE, A2,$E$1),TEXTJOIN(" • ", TRUE, A2,$F$1))
```

gives me a nice little column

```
dog • pink
dog • red
dog • orange
```

but when i try to make it loop through every value in colA by amending it to

```
=VSTACK(TEXTJOIN(" • ", TRUE, A2:A,$B$1),TEXTJOIN(" • ", TRUE, A2:A,$C$1),TEXTJOIN(" • ", TRUE, A2:A,$D$1),TEXTJOIN(" • ", TRUE, A2:A,$E$1),TEXTJOIN(" • ", TRUE, A2:A,$F$1))
```

I just get three cells of data with a lot of joined words within instead of what I want, which is 12 stacked cells of data.

Haven't even touched the "skip the blank cell" issue.

Not sure if I've explained well.

Answer (score 1):

*You may try:*

```js
=tocol(index(if(len(B2:D),A2:A&" • "&B1:D1,)),1)
```

[image]

Comment: now if in column H i want to stack accompanying X values for the cross-cell, how would i do that? i have currently 
=let(v,VSTACK(B2:5,C2:5,D2:5,),SORT(FILTER(v,v<>""),0,-1))
but that goes down columns instead of across rows, so the values mixmatch

Comment: Please do share a test sheet recreating this scenario of yours and also enter the expected output *manually* so that it gives a clear picture of what is needed...

Comment: Oh I think I just got it @rockinfreakshow! Thank you so much for all your help. Got the desired outcome by reusing your previous formula and just amending slightly to get =tocol(index(if(len(B2:D5),B2:I,)),1)